# Scrolling with Trackpad

Tags: touchpad

I have a Lenovo G550, I want to activate the scrolling (right border) of my touchpad.

It works with Windows, but in Ubuntu I can't find the way to do it.

I see "Mouse config", Scrolling is activated but it doens't work.

Any idea?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Press <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F2</kbd> and paste `gnome-mouse-properties`.

Then go to touchpad and select "Edge scrolling".

[image]

Comment: Good answer, but this is already activated!

Comment: Well then it looks like a bug? Is it something like this:  https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/xserver-xorg-input-synaptics/+bug/773577

Comment: I think is a driver problem, cos on Windows I have to install a synaptic soft.